# Not creating a db table using installschema

Tags: php, database, magento2

I have created a custom module in magneto2.

Module enabled and setup file created in setup_module table.
But Table did not created. I am using magneto 2.0.3 version

This is my InstallSchema.php file.

```
<?php

    namespace Magento\Bundle\Setup;

    use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

    class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
    {
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
         */
        public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
        {
            $installer = $setup;

            $installer->startSetup();
            $table = $installer->getConnection()
                ->newTable($installer->getTable('test_sample'))
                ->addColumn(
                    'id',
                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    null,
                    ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
                    'Id'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'name',
                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    null,
                    [],
                    'name'
                )
                ->setComment('testing');

            $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
            $installer->endSetup();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code for creating table seems fine.
However I think the file is never loaded and run. From what I can see     `namespace Magento\Bundle\Setup;` is wrong if this is in your custom module.